# Unable to show polyline in Google Maps Directions using react-google-maps-api

Tags: google-maps, google-directions-api, google-polyline, react-google-maps, react-google-maps-api

---

---

I am trying to show directions on google map. I am getting correct directions data but direction renderer only showing origin and destination markers but polyline or precisely route is missing between them. I am using react google maps api library. Any help would be appreciated

I was expecting origin and destination markers and polyline or precisely route between them but I got only markers not route between them

```
import {
    GoogleMap,
    useLoadScript,
    Marker,
    MarkerF,
    DirectionsRenderer,
    Polyline,
} from "@react-google-maps/api";
const center = { lat: 31.5882, lng: 74.3154 };
const libraries = ["places"];
const mapContainerStyle = {
    height: "375px",
    width: "100%",
};
const mapOptions = {
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    zoomControl: true,
};
const polyOptions = {
    strokeColor: "red",
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: "#FF0000",
    fillOpacity: 0.35,
    clickable: false,
    draggable: false,
    editable: false,
    visible: true,
    zIndex: 1,
};
const [directionsResponse, setDirectionsResponse] =
        useState(null);
const [distance, setDistance] = useState("");
const [duration, setDuration] = useState("");
const [polypath, setPolypath] = useState([]);
const [marker, setMarker] = useState({
    start: null,
    end: null,
});
const [map, setMap] = useState(
/** @type google.maps.Map */ (null)
const { isLoaded, loadError } = useLoadScript({
    googleMapsApiKey:
        process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY,
    libraries,
});
const onMapLoad = useCallback((map) => {
    setMap(map);
}, []);
const handleDirections = async (
    ) => {
        const origin = { lat: 31.5882, lng: 74.3154 };
        const destination = { lat: 31.5773, lng: 74.3363 };
        const request = {
            origin,
            destination,
            // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
            travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
        };
        const directionsService =
            new google.maps.DirectionsService();
        await directionsService.route(
            request,
            function (response, status) {
                if (status == "OK") {
                    setDistance(
                        response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.text
                    );
                    setDuration(
                        response.routes[0].legs[0].duration.text
                    );
                    setDirectionsResponse(response);
                    var leg = response.routes[0].legs[0];
                    setMarker({
                        ...marker,
                        start: leg.start_location,
                        end: leg.end_location,
                    });
                } else {
                    console.log("Error getting directions");
                }
            }
        );
};
return (
<div>
                {distance != "" && <p>Distance: {distance}</p>}
                {duration != "" && <p>Time Duration: {duration}</p>}
            </div>
            {/* {JSON.stringify(location.currentLocation, null, 4)} */}
            <div style={{ width: "100%", height: "375px" }}>
                {loadError ? (
                    "Error Loading Map"
                ) : isLoaded ? (
                    <GoogleMap
                        id="map"
                        mapContainerStyle={mapContainerStyle}
                        zoom={15}
                        center={center}
                        options={mapOptions}
                        onClick={onMapClick}
                        onLoad={onMapLoad}
                    >
                        {marker.start != null && marker.end != null && (
                            <>
                                <MarkerF
                                    key={`${marker.start.lat()}-${marker.start.lng()}`}
                                    position={{
                                        lat: marker.start.lat(),
                                        lng: marker.start.lng(),
                                    }}
                                    onClick={() => {
                                        return;
                                    }}
                                    icon={{
                                        url: `/images/pin.png`,
                                        origin: new window.google.maps.Point(
                                            0,
                                            0
                                        ),
                                        anchor: new window.google.maps.Point(
                                            15,
                                            15
                                        ),
                                        scaledSize: new window.google.maps.Size(
                                            30,
                                            30
                                        ),
                                    }}
                                />
                                <MarkerF
                                    key={`${marker.end.lat()}-${marker.end.lng()}`}
                                    position={{
                                        lat: marker.end.lat(),
                                        lng: marker.end.lng(),
                                    }}
                                    onClick={() => {
                                        return;
                                    }}
                                    icon={{
                                        url: `/images/rider.png`,
                                        origin: new window.google.maps.Point(
                                            0,
                                            0
                                        ),
                                        anchor: new window.google.maps.Point(
                                            15,
                                            15
                                        ),
                                        scaledSize: new window.google.maps.Size(
                                            30,
                                            30
                                        ),
                                    }}
                                />
                            </>
                        )}
                        {directionsResponse && (
                            <DirectionsRenderer
                                directions={directionsResponse}
                                options={{
                                    suppressMarkers: true,
                                }}
                            />
                        )}
                    </GoogleMap>
                ) : (
                    <h1>Loading map...</h1>
                )}
            </div>
        </div>
);
```

[Lat Lng Data is being pushed to another array making it nested](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Flo1L.png)

[This is exactly how map looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFOkl.png)

Comment: Can you provide a code snippet? Like one from codesandbox. The community needs a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces the issue to be able to look into it.